# OkHttp 504 Gatweway time out error in android

Tags: android, post, web, service, okhttp

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=504, message=GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, url=https://************************}
```

I am getting

```
code=504, message=GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
```

in android but the same url got success in iOS

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(urlStr).post(formBody)
            .addHeader("Authorization", g.getTokenType() + " " + g.getAccessToken())
            .addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    try {
        Response mResponse = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String jsonString = mResponse.body().string();
```

Comment: check your server and will you please try again.

Comment: @HimeshGoswami its working fine in iOS

Comment: are you using an emulator or physical device?

Comment: @MohammadTabbara I am using physical device

Comment: @shiva are you to trying to sending the image in this api?

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal Nope... I am not sending any image... its a normal data

Comment: @shiva than try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49643973/6096821 with time out of near about 5 minutes.

Comment: are the iOS and Android phones using the same internet connection? Did you try another android device? just knowing the error is 504 is vast check https://www.lifewire.com/504-gateway-timeout-error-explained-2622941 for more info.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara Yes both are in same network... and it happens in all android device

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but sometimes server sided problems may be device specific check this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/808550/504-gateway-time-out-only-on-android-devices

Comment: if i removed retryOnConnectionFailure(false) in my code its working fine... but i am getting duplicate hit on my server. So that i add retryOnConnectionFailure(false)..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30*1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        .build();
```

Comment: this is my response   -     Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=504, message=GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, url=https://web-***.*******.com/***************************************}

Answer (score 0):

Put the timeout in minutes as per your server speed time requirement.

Try this :-

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder();
                builder.method(original.method(), original.body());
                builder.header("Accept", "application/json");
                if (TOKEN.length() > 0)
                    builder.header("Authorization", TOKEN);
                return chain.proceed(builder.build());
            }
        });

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
```

Comment: Than check the url which you are entering is 100% correct or not ?Like http or https, domain name, etc.

Comment: if i removed  retryOnConnectionFailure(false) in my code its working fine... but i am getting duplicate hit on my server. So that i add retryOnConnectionFailure(false)